# How to show UiviewController from NSObject Class?

Tags: core-bluetooth

I'm Working with Core Bluetooth Framework. In this app I had to connect multiple Bluetooth device with the iPhone and when Bluetooth device goes out of range it shows an alert.

Instead of this alert I want to show UIViewController.All the coding of Alert is handled on NSObject Classes.
Here is the Screen which I want to show instead of AlertView

[image]

Comment: I don't think that the real problem is related to `CoreBluetooth.framework`...

Comment: @Larme you are right, CoreBluetooth is the framework upon which I'm working.At a stage when Bluetooth is disconnected from iPhone, I want to show this screen using NSObject.

Comment: Well, what your real question? What can't you do ? Where are you blocked? What have you time done?

Comment: @Larne Lets Come to chat I'll brief you about my problem if it is possible for you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly you need a reference to an active UIViewController in an object of NSObject subclass.
So when instancing NSObject that currently handles AlertView send it a reference to an active UIViewController, something like this if you're instancing it from an active UIViewController:

```
NSObjectSubclass *alertViewHandler = [[NSObjectSubclass alloc] init];
[alertViewHandler setActiveViewController:self];
```

and then later in your alertViewHandler instead of showing an alert you can do this:

```
[activeViewController presentViewController:viewControllerToPresent animated:YES completion:nil];
```

There are many more different solutions to your problem but with limited information I can only guess which one suits you best.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it :
- Create a delegate on your Communication Class.
- Set your ViewController as its delegate.
- Tell the delegate when the peripheral is disconnected, and it will show your custom screen screen...

Answer (score 0):

Likewise Every Problem has a solution, with this in mind I tried and got a solution

To Show a UiViewController from NSObject - I use the reference from App Delegate Class because AppDelegate has its own UIViewController and I use that wind override with my UIViewController.

In the above case I can't go with pushViewController or PresentViewController because all the functionalities work inside the ViewController since I had to call view from the NSObject, so I think this is the best and easy way to such kind of problems.